# Python: search global classes in a single module file

Tags: python, python-module, global

I have a Python 2.x `module.py` file that looks like this:

```
class A(object):
    KEYWORD = 'Class A'

class B(A):
    KEYWORD = 'Class B'

class C(object):
    pass

def list_class_keywords():
    for name in globals():
        print name, hasattr(name, 'KEYWORD')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_class_keywords()
```

In `list_class_keywords()`, I'm looping through all of the objects of this file module and testing if the object has an attribute `KEYWORD`. Clearly it isn't working, since `name` is a string. How should I rewrite `list_classes` to get what I'm looking for?

---

**Update:** thanks to Ignacio for the hint. Here is the updated code:

```
def list_class_keywords():
    global_dict = globals()
    for name in global_dict:
        obj = global_dict[name]
        print name, hasattr(obj, 'KEYWORD')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A(object):
    KEYWORD = 'Class A'

class B(A):
    KEYWORD = 'Class B'

class C(object):
    pass

def list_class_keywords():
    for name, obj in globals().items():
        print name, hasattr(obj, 'KEYWORD')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_class_keywords()
```

Answer (score 3):

`globals()` is a dictionary. Index it.

But you should be using a decorator to enumerate the classes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but you can `eval()` a string that is a name, and it will get an object with  that name. If that happens to be a class, then it should work.

Test:

```
>>>> class Object:
....     pass
.... 
>>>> eval("Object")
<class __main__.Object at 0x0000000102a62bc0>
>>>>
```

UPDATE: The other answer is much better.